# Avoiding partial lines at bottom of screen

Tags: faces

Is there a way to avoid only partially visible lines at the bottom of the
screen, such as in this picture?

[image]

Perhaps this could be achieved by adding some empty space below the
minibuffer and echo area, if that is possible.

(Using Emacs 26.1 and i3.)

Comment: What alternative behaviour are you looking for?

Comment: @phils, I think it would be nice if enough empty space were added below the minibuffer to make the height of the text area a multiple of the line height.  It looks as if Termite is using this kind of solution.

Comment: Have you looked at `frame-resize-pixelwise` and `window-resize-pixelwise`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package [multicolumn](https://github.com/Lindydancer/multicolumn). It allows you, among else, to resize and reposition a frame so that it contains a number of side-by-side windows. The height of the editing area becomes a multiple of the height of the default font -- which ensures that there is no line clipping (as long as you don't mix fonts with different hights).